# Phalcon for Windows and PHP 5.5

Tags: phalcon

Is there any way to get Phalcon DLL for PHP 5.5?

Phalcon DLL for PHP 5.4 provided here:

http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows

does not work with my XAMP 5.5.3 PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile it your own:

http://szdredd.blogspot.cz/2013/11/how-to-setup-phalcon-framework-under.html?showComment=1385412595836#c3025679067378957109

or download precompiled DLL for PHP 5.5.5 (which works for 5.5.3) here:

https://github.com/andont/phalcon-win